# multidimensional "WHERE IN" condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

As is well-known, we can simplify

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE X=1 OR X=4 OR X=9
```

as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE X IN (1,4,9)
```

Is there a similar shortcut possible for "multidimensional" conditions as in the following:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE (X=1 AND Y=2) OR (X=4 AND Y=3) OR (X=9 AND Y=5)
```

in a form resembling something like this

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE [X,Y] IN ( [1,2], [4,3], [9,5] )
```

?

I would be willing to count anything as a simplification that uses O(n) characters where the factor is significantly smaller than in the naive example (i.e., adding one more case makes the query string grow by less than `OR (X=... AND Y=...)`) even though there is perhaps more constant overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you may use `WHERE IN (...)` with tuples in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (x, y) IN ((1, 2), (4, 3), (9, 5));
```

### Demo

Comment: Wait there *are* tuples? That sillifies my question completely ...

Comment: No, it's not really a silly question, because other than MySQL (and MariaDB), most other databases don't support this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from tbl
where (c_a, c_b) in (select c_a, c_b  from tbl_2);
```

[here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ed1de72f5d10b2ba14490398413e0d5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONCAT` function with delimiter in next way:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE CONCAT(X,'&',Y) IN ( '1&2', '4&3', '9&5' );
```

or more visual:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE CONCAT('[', X, ',', Y, ']') IN ( '[1,2]', '[4,3]', '[9,5]' );
```